# Excel 2013 upgrade "broke" my VBA function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

The attached code is meant as a table of contents builder.  Depending on what row the function is on, it plucks certain cells from subsequent worksheets.

```
Asset        Location   Model 
__________________________________________________________
Freezer      Kitchen    Freezerator 5000 (from worksheet 2)
Television   Den        Panasung 55" (from worksheet 3, etc.)
```

Before the "upgrade", the function just worked.  Now, it works if I edit sells, but if I copy cells within the same worksheet (anywhere, not just the "special" cells), the cells flicker and flicker for many seconds and then resolve.  Sometimes it fails with an overflow error (if I recall correctly, it didn't do it today.)  Copying cells from one worksheet to another just works with no such delay.

If I comment out the Application.Volatile line, the delays go away, but the function does nothing.

Code:

```
'Return values in subsequent worksheets based on row that the function
'is located on.  Usage in this particular instance is a TOC
'Num = number of rows to offset, based on starting position of the TOC
'and skipping any worksheets not to be included in the TOC
'srow and scol is the target cell on the following worksheets

Function GetSpot(num, srow, scol)
    Application.Volatile
    If num > (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count) Then
      GetSpot = " "
    Else
      GetSpot = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(num).Cells(srow, scol).Value
    End If
    If GetSpot = 0 Then GetSpot = " "
End Function
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Flickering can be resolved by adding `ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of your code and set back to True at the end.  Curious - If you know the exact sheet, row & col then why not just link the cells directly and not use a function?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing is a bug in Office 2013 related to user-defined function use within a worksheet. We reported this to Microsoft and were told it will not be made part of a hotfix release as only 3 other people have reported it.

When you have a user-defined function within your worksheet and you perform an action such as copy/paste or insert rows, the worksheet takes painstakingly long to complete calculation. This occurs anytime you have a selection where there are `marching ants` (for lack of a better term) around the selection and the worksheet with user-defined functions calculates.

It's not your function, it's Office 2013. Here's a quick way to replicate the issue:

- Create a new blank workbook
- Open Visual Basic Editor and add a new `Module`
- Paste the following VBA in the module

  `Function TimesTwo(ver)
      TimesTwo = ver * 2
   End Function`

[image]

- On the workbook, paste the formula `=INT(RAND()*8)` into cell `A1`
- In the range `D1:F100`, paste the formula `=TimesTwo($A$1)`
- After configuring the workbook like the above, perform a copy and paste within that worksheet.

The result is that the calculation will take a very long time to complete, which can be seen in the `status bar`.

There are no workarounds aside from using `native Excel functions, if available` or working with the Workbook `Calculation` set to `Manual`. That is, disabling calculation of the worksheet until you manually invoke it.